# How can I reduce a WordPress footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

I'm trying to reduce the height of a footer in my WordPress Website.

Apparently (check the picture linked) the style is directly in the div but I failed finding it in my WP files.

Can anyone help me with this?
[Capture of the html inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODEZJ.png)

Comment: as I checked your screenshot I think this would be generated dynamically so if you need to force reduce height of widget you can add some css styles and add `!important` to it 
for example `.widget-area.masonry{ max-height: 100px !important` 
I hope this will help you. if it does let me know to change it to answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are not acceptable here. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes the relevant code in your question, so that we are able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dev tools show styles like this. Its an indicator it's being controlled by JS.

```
element.styles{
   position: relative;
   height: 122px
}
```

As your JS is loading after your css (as it should be), you need to override the property after JS is called. This is one of the few times you should add !important to your css. So to override the JS height you need something like this

```
.site-footer .widget-area{
   height: 400px !important;
}
```